# Three.js - seam (white line) appears when rotating attached objects

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, geometry

I'm seeing seam line (see 1st image below) when rotating 3 geometries with calculated textures put together inside a THREE.Object3D() as their parent object. It looks fine when viewed on some angles (see 2nd image below).

Is there a way to get rid of those lines? Thanks in advance.

Angle with visible cut line

[image: Angle with visible cut line]

Angle that looks fine

[image: Angle that looks fine]

Comment: Are those two different textures? And two different plane geometries? Can you provide a fiddle or something to demonstrate this?

Comment: Actually its 3x boxGeometry with texture image put together to create rectangular image and added those 3 inside an empty THREE.Object3D() to hold them together. The result is the image you see. But my problem is when I rotate the parent object of those 3 boxgeometries it show a seam line (see picture 1)